# Text is stuck in the center and its size cannot be changed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem with stuck text in the middle of screen. I'm wondering why this text 'Najnowsze ogłoszenia' is still in the center and its size does not change despite I set it to:

```
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
```

[image]

I want to have in on the left and I want to change its size. What am I making wrong? The code I have written:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:../constants/AppConstants.dart';
import 'package:../ui/pages/home/page/Advertisement.dart';
import 'package:../util/HttpActions.dart';

import '../../SizedBox.dart';
import 'Advertisement.dart';
import 'BottomAppBar.dart';
import 'FAB.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String jwt;

  const HomePage(this.jwt);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();

  factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(jwt);
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  late final String jwt;
  late Future<List<Items>> _listOfItems;
  final searchTextController = TextEditingController();
...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF9F9FC),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: buildFAB(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppBar(),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25, top: 25),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: searchTextController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Szukaj',
                      fillColor: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                      filled: true),
                ),
                buildSizedBox(10.0),
                Text(
                  'Najnowsze ogłoszenia',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                buildSizedBox(10.0),
                FutureBuilder<List<Items>>(
                  future: _listOfItems,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                      return Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, top: 5),
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                advertisementCard(
                                    snapshot.data![index], context),
                            separatorBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

 ...
}
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Column` it's in has `mainAxisAlignment` set to center.
Wrap your `Text` widget inside a `Row` and set the row's mainAxisAlignment to start.

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
 children:[
  Text(
   'Najnowsze ogłoszenia',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    ),
 ]),
```

Comment: or simply set the ``crossAxisAlignment`` property to ``CrossAxisAlignment.start`` as: ``Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [])``

Comment: But I think OP want's the other widgets under the Text widget centered.

Comment: They will be in the center.

Comment: This may be a workaround, but not a solution, as it gives a bad UI when the device is turned to landscape mode.